# shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer

Tags: maven, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm working on a maven project. I'm trying to integrate jmh benchmarking into my project. The pom.xml of my maven project...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-root</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>platform-migration</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Platform Migration</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compile.source>1.7</maven.compile.source>
    <maven.compile.target>1.7</maven.compile.target>
    <jmh.version>1.1.1</jmh.version>
    <jersey-version>2.22.1</jersey-version>
    <uberjar.name>rest-benchmarks</uberjar.name>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jmh.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
        <version>${jmh.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I build my project using "mvn clean install", I got following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.0.0:shade (default) on project platform-migration: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.0.0:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer -> [Help 1]
```

I don't understand why this error is happening?

Answer (score 49):

Found a cause of this affecting my own setup and am sharing here in case it helps others.

In my case, the cause is a parent pom containing the `maven-shade-plugin` configuration as well as my own pom.  The way that Maven merges these works out incorrectly.  It appears the Maven is matching the `transformer` tags in the order they appear and merging them.

To figure this out, use `mvn help:effective-pom` and look for the resulting `maven-shade-plugin` configuration.  In my case, a `<resource>` tag was added to the `ManifestResourceTransformer`, and this resource matched the first entry in the parent pom's `maven-shade-plugin` configuration.

Adding an `<id>` to the `<execution>` eliminates the problem:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>shade-my-jar</id>
...
```

I suspect both configurations were using the same, default ID.  So the key is that each execution of the plugin have a unique id.

Comment: And if you need to prevent the parent execution from running, you can specify its id, then set phase to "none": <execution><id>parent-id</id><phase>none</phase></execution>

Answer (score 0):

The **ManifestResourceTransformer** allows existing entries in the **MANIFEST** to be replaced and new entries added.

For example, the following sample sets

- the Main-Class entry to the value of the app.main.class property,
- the X-Compile-Source-JDK entry to the value of the maven.compile.source property and
- the X-Compile-Target-JDK entry to the value of the maven.compile.target property.

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>${app.main.class}</Main-Class>
                    <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                    <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I think this is the right Configuration

Comment: I encountered the same problem, neither of above configurations worked. In fact, both(**mainClass** and **manifestEntries**) are supported. But in my local machine(Windows 10, Java 8,  maven shade plugin 3.1), it always complained the *resource* not found when packaging my project. My configuration is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/groovy-dsl/pom.xml).

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration looks wrong:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>xxxxxxxxxxx</Main-Class>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```